# How can I search through all Stack Exchange sites at once?

Tags: support, stackexchange, search

Including Area 51, Super User, meta... everything. Is there a simple way to do it in one search?

I'm pretty sure Google-tweaking could do it, but I'd rather have an online tool for it - even if it's just an updated custom Google with updated family sites.

This must be a duplicated question, but I couldn't find any related ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should search at [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com)

[image]

[Blog post:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/)

> We just added a custom Google search for all of our sites at the top of http://stackexchange.com.